# TempDir is null

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I want to copy some files into a temporary directory. But the `File` I annotate with `@TempDir` does not seem to get injected.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.io.TempDir;

import java.io.File;

public class MyTempFileTest {

    @TempDir
    public File tempFolder;
    
    @Test
    public void testTempFolder() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(tempFolder); 
    }
 }
```

the result is `org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: not <null>`

I would instead expect it to be a random temporary directory, as was the case with `@Rule TemporaryFolder tmpSudokus = new TemporaryFolder()` in Junit4.

And according to the [docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.7.2/user-guide/#writing-tests-built-in-extensions-TempDirectory) I can annotate a `Java.io.File`.

If I try to pass the tempDir as a directory

```
    @Test
    public void testTempFolderParam(@TempDir File tempFolder) {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(tempFolder);
    }
```

I get `org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [java.io.File tempFolder] in executable [public void my.package.MyTempFileTest.testTempFolderParam(java.io.File)].`

The test is part of an android project, my dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.2'
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you running your JUnit test cases? Which exact version of JUnit (and their runners?) are you using?

Comment: @Progman I'm running the tests by right clicking on the class in Android studio's `project` sidebar. I'll update my question once I've figured out how to run a single test class in a gradle subproject. I assume I am running JUnit `5.7.2` as specified in my dependencies and I do not explicitly specify a runner, so I assume its version is the same. I don't know how to find out the version.

Comment: same for me, tempFolder is null ...using junit-jupiter-api v5.7.2, but using `@TempDir static Path tempFolder;` not File

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation [Junit5 Docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/io/TempDir.html)

> The temporary directory is only created if a field in a test class or a parameter in a lifecycle method or test method is annotated with @TempDir. **If the field type or parameter type is neither Path nor File or if the temporary directory cannot be created, an ExtensionConfigurationException or a ParameterResolutionException will be thrown as appropriate**. In addition, a ParameterResolutionException will be thrown for a constructor parameter annotated with @TempDir.

As I see in your example, you did use java.io.File so I guess your problem is in the creation part of the temporary folder.

I copied your example and it did work, the tempDir was not null

[image]

Dependencies :

- junit-jupiter:5.7.2
- junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2
- junit-jupiter-params:5.7.2